# maven-shade-plugin: exclude a dependency and all its transitive dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

Using `maven-shade-plugin`, is there a way to exclude a dependency (which is not `provided`) *and all its transitive dependencies*?

For example :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    ... other dependencies

</dependencies>
```

and 1)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*:*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>com.example:some-artifact</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

or 2)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*:*</include>
                    </includes>
                </artifactSet>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>com.example:some-artifact</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Those don't work.

All the transitive dependencies of `com.example:some-artifact` are added to the final jar.

Note that I don't want to set the scope of `com.example:some-artifact` to `provided`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run "shade" from within a profile, and mark your dependency as provided only in that profile. For example:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>shadeProfile</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
                <version>1.23</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

When you run `mvn -PshadeProfile package` it will treat your dependency as provided (and thus omit its dependencies), and it will use the classifier "shaded" so you can use this as a dependency in other modules.

Comment: It's important to know that if you have a non-provided dependency (even a transitive one) on one of the transitive dependencies of your "some-artifact", then that artifact WILL be included by the shade plugin. As a result, sometimes this solution will not achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 11):

I tried following configuration, and it worked for me also:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>client-${artifactId}</finalName>
        <filters>
            <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
        </filters>
        <artifactSet>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>org.apache.jmeter:*</exclude>
                <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:*</exclude>
                <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.11:*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </artifactSet>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: 'provided' and 'exclude' are the same at the end?

Answer (score 1):

You must take in mind that by default all dependencies COMPILE will be included. But if you set artifacts in artifactSet includes, only those will be considered and the rest will be excluded (dependencies and its transitive dependencies)

Sometimes it's easier include only the dependencies you need than exclude all the rest.